# How to rearrange the elements of a matrix in Matlab according to the order of elements in another matrix?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

I have a vector `A` in Matlab of dimension `(mxn)x1` composed by real numbers greater or equal then zero, e.g. `m=3,n=4` `A=[1;0;0;0;0.4;0.7;0.5;0.6;0.8;0;1;6]` which looks like

```
           A=[1
              0 
              0 
              ---
              0 
              0.4 
              0.7 
              ---
              0.5 
              0.6 
              0.8
              ---
              0 
              1 
              6]
```

We can see that `A` is composed by `n` subvectors of dimension `m`. I have a vector `B` of dimension `gx1`, with `g` greater or equal than `m`, composed by ones and zeros such that the total number of ones is equal to `m`, e.g. `g=9` `B=[1;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1]` which looks like

```
B=[1 
   0 
   0 
   0 
   0 
   0 
   0 
   1 
   1]
```

I want to create a matrix `C` of dimension `gxn` in which the entries of each subvector of `A` are placed in correspondence of the ones in `g` for each column of `B`, e.g.

```
C=[1 | 0  |  0.5 | 0
   0 | 0  |  0   | 0
   0 | 0  |  0   | 0
   0 | 0  |  0   | 0
   0 | 0  |  0   | 0
   0 | 0  |  0   | 0
   0 | 0  |  0   | 0
   0 | 0.4|  0.6 | 1
   0 | 0.7|  0.8 | 6]
```

Loops are fine only if very fast. Real dimensions of matrices are very large (e.g. `mxn=100000, g=50000`)

Comment: Could you provide the example matrices in valid syntax? For A I'm not sure what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1 (`bsxfun` based linear indexing)**

```
C = zeros(g,n)                         %// Pre-allocate
idx = bsxfun(@plus,find(B),[0:n-1]*g)  %// Indices where A elements are to be put
C(idx)= A                              %// Put A elements
```

**Approach #2 (Direct replacement)**

```
C = zeros(g,n) 
C(find(B),:) = reshape(A,m,[])
```

---

**Pre-allocation**: For [`faster pre-allocation`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance) you can do this instead in both of the above mentioned approaches -

```
C(g,n) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and logical indexing approach.  First, reshape your data so that it's in the right matrix form, so in your case `3 x 4`, then use `B` as a logical mask and replicate it for as many times as we have columns in your matrix, then do an assignment.  You would have to allocate a matrix that is the size of your desired output before doing this assignment. Something like this:

```
%// Your example data
m = 3; n = 4;
A = [1;0;0;0;0.4;0.7;0.5;0.6;0.8;0;1;6];
B = logical([1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]).';

%// Relevant code
Am = reshape(A, m, n);
Bm = repmat(B, 1, n);
C = zeros(numel(B), 4);
C(Bm) = Am;
```

`C` is the desired result, where we get:

```
C =

    1.0000         0    0.5000         0
         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0
         0    0.4000    0.6000    1.0000
         0    0.7000    0.8000    6.0000
```

My gut feeling is that this will be slower than the `bsxfun` approach, but the above is more readable if you're not familiar with how `bsxfun` works.